# Meaning of designation for student

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm studying MS in a university, and have been asked to provide my "designation", as shown below:

[image]

What do I need to add in the "designation" field?

Comment: When you looked *designation* up in the dictionary, what did it say? After reading that definition, what still confuses you? If you edit to add this information to the question, I'd be happy to reopen it :)

Comment: it shows that "an official title or name:". So can I say that my title is a student?

Comment: It needs more context;please care to add.

Comment: I think a designation is whatever the official title of the degree is, like *MLIS* (Master of Library and Information Science), though it could also be something general like *MS* or *M.Sc.* (Master of Science).  I don't really hear the term *designation* much in this context, though, so it's possible I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: It could be asking whether you are a graduate or undergraduate student. It's hard to say. Have you tried submitting the form with that field blank? Maybe you will get a helpful error message. If all else fails, just enter whatever you think is best. If you're wrong, you'll at least indicate to them that their form could be more clear.

Comment: Just after adding the form filed, it looks like the question is making more sense now. According to me, it would be your latest degree you completed.

Comment: For example, here in India, if a student is PhD., MSc. (Masters in Science) in Physics from [IIT Delhi](http://www.iitd.ac.in) and BSc. (Bachelor in Science) from [Calcutta University](http://www.caluniv.ac.in), he would probably write `Dr. Name Surname, PhD, MSc in Physcis(IIT Delhi), Bsc. (Calcutta University)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write designation as "Student"

In college we can see different level of persons like Teachers, Head of the Department, Principal, Peons and Students etc…If others have designation like Teacher, Head of the Department etc…Then Students Designation is  “Student”.

Comment: Sorry, but as it currently stands, it looks just like a comment, without further elaboration, this answer is most likely going to be deleted anyway.